# Where did some 3K questions go?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I saw question #4,000,000 on SO earlier today, and even [congratulated its author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425618/function-with-default-parameter-as-template-type/13425747#comment18349386_13425618). But later almost three thousand questions disappeared, so we are back at under 4M questions (3,997,446 as of now). I am curious what has happened to these other questions, or was it simply a counter glitch?

Comment: Trivia: over 4.5 million questions have been posted on Stack Overflow since the early private beta. 530K deleted, 234K by their authors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like 3900-ish questions have been deleted since between November 16, 2012 00:00:00 UTC and now.

Most of these were from our [automatic deletion script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) + a couple edge cases to handle rejected migrations.

I'm not sure what else to tell you here beyond "Stack Overflow has a lot of traffic, and a lot of questions are posted and deleted". :)

Comment: That's a *lot* of auto-deleted questions in one fell swoop (or in a few very short bursts).